# Overriding CTRL+Click behavior on a link

Tags: javascript, html

I need to override the crtl+click on a link in HTML or Javascript. I would like it so that when an user does a crtl+click on a link, instead of the doing the default behavior of the browser, it performs my function instead. I'm unable to use jQuery to do this. Any ideas?

This is the function that I want to call:

```
function alertMe()
{
alert('overwrote the crtl click');
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use jquery? Is this an assignment or built in limitations?

Comment: What exactly does Ctrl+Click *do* that you want to prevent? Probably very different things on your machine and on mine.

Comment: _We_ don't understand what _you_ mean...

Comment: I want crtl click to excute a function that I created

Comment: [Then perhaps you could update your question with that information, along with code you've already tried, and your expected behaviour.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I answered because you don't want jQuery and I admire that

Comment: The lack of jquery is because of built in limitations

Comment: There's absolutely no problem with not using jQuery...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture the click event, and see if the control button is held down using `event.ctrlKey`

```
document.getElementById("datAnchor").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        //your code here
    }
    // else do nothing with e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

If you meant all anchor tags, you'll have to get fancy with the selector and throw it into a loop like..

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("a"), function(element) {
    //code from other sample in here, except replace the
    //getElementById with `this`
});
```

For event fancier selectors, `document.querySelectorAll` should suit your benefits.

Comment: how do you capture the click event (I don't want to overwrite the 'onclick'

Comment: Notice how I used [addEventListner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)?

Comment: Sorry, I edited. Somebody showed me I wanted `e.ctrlKey` not the which/keyCode.

Comment: my code did execute but the default function of crtl click still worked, so how do I prevent that?

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` should be called first then.